# How to extract the URL from a link that was not created by a formula?

Tags: google-sheets

In  Google Sheets, I have a column with ~17,000 rows each containing text and a hyperlink. The link was not created using a formula and is only displayed when you hover over the cell.

I need to copy ONLY the links from the first column to the neighboring column. It would take years to do this manually and I can't find a quick solution on the internet.

How do I extract the URLs from the links?

[Link to Sample Spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/16hbHiMut3aaU_a7y2g3XrAUc1fv6i3iO_eVibLK_7-Y/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Do you need to do this in Sheets? I think it might only be possible with Google Apps Script if so. Otherwise, I could give you a solution involving copying/pasting into other webapps, which I think could be done in less than 5 minutes. Obviously, this means that you would have to update it manually if more rows were added to the sheet.

Answer (score 1):

Use a custom function such as my [RichTextLinks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75028882/13045193). Use it like this:

```
=RichTextLinks("A1:A1000", A1:A1000)
```

I maintain the code at the Stack link above, so you can always refer to it to get the latest version.